# Electron showing blank page when opens

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am using Electron with angular2. When I open the app for the first time (`electron .`), it opens a blank page. It seems like no DOM loaded. But if I resize/move the window, the DOM suddenly appears.

The DOM won't appear till I resize/move the window. To overcome this issue I am manually increasing the width of window by Electron, and this is not the ultimate solution. Any idea, why this is happening and how to fix this?

UPDATE: Here is the snapshot of my index.html

[image]

Comment: Can you share your index.html?

Comment: @golodenko Added the screenshot of my index.html

Comment: Looks like a Chromium bug with rendering. For normal website checking other browser would confirm but for electron, it's not an option. I would try to bug this turning off plugins and parts of app one-by-one.